# Compiz-like effects on OS X

Tags: unix, desktop, macos

I recently moved from Linux to OS X.

So far nothing has disappointed me but I miss the [compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) desktop effects I used to have on my Debian (on Ubuntu before I moved to Debian) with xfce and compiz like 3D effects, desktop workspaces in 3D view and many more:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried searching for equivalent or similar stuff for OS X but no luck.  Looking forward to making my OS X desktop experience like (or even better than) compiz.

Comment: Could you elaborate which compiz desktop effects you miss on OS X? Could you provide links or screenshots? Compiz has lots of features and your description "those 3-d effects, desktop workspaces in 3d view and many more" lacks detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out [Deskovery](http://www.neomobili.com/products/deskovery/):

> Efficient and fun window management.
>
> Stop wasting time to find, align, place and resize your windows. Manage your windows efficiently with fun and simplicity in the pure Mac style !

It has some of the features of [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org), such as wobbly windows and window shading.

Comment: it says purchase. Ain't there anything for free?